# group by iteration plus group when repeating two fields in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have the following array:

```
[
{name:"jhon",surname:"connor",age:21},
{name:"jhonny",surname:"lator",age:22},
{name:"celia",surname:"mcgregor",age:23},
{name:"raul",surname:"fernandez",age:25},
{name:"marcela",surname:"fernandez",age:25},
{name:"omar",surname:"caster",age:26},
{name:"luna",surname:"potter",age:30},
{name:"harry",surname:"potter",age:30},
]
```

and I want to have the following order:

```
[
{order:1,name:"jhon",surname:"connor",age:21},
{order:2,name:"jhonny",surname:"lator",age:22},
{order:3,name:"celia",surname:"mcgregor",age:23},
{order:4,name:"raul",surname:"fernandez",age:25},
{order:4,name:"marcela",surname:"fernandez",age:25},
{order:5,name:"omar",surname:"caster",age:26},
{order:6,name:"luna",surname:"potter",age:30},
{order:6,name:"harry",surname:"potter",age:30},
]
```

If the last name and age are the same, don't count in the iteration of the order.

in javascript.

Comment: Not sure what type of data format that is; it's definitely invalid though: you should put quotes around your strings.

Comment: sorry, my fault, I'll update the array

Comment: I don't understand your question; based on your example the only difference is that you added an incrementing `order` key in each object...

Comment: not completely, if you look at the last two objects, which meet the condition of having the same surnames and ages, the order is not repeated, it has the same one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go (Added descriptive comments in the below code snippet) **:**

```js
// Input array
const arr = [
  {name:"jhon",surname:"connor",age:21},
  {name:"jhonny",surname:"lator",age:22},
  {name:"celia",surname:"mcgregor",age:23},
  {name:"raul",surname:"fernandez",age:25},
  {name:"luna",surname:"potter",age:30},
  {name:"marcela",surname:"fernandez",age:25},
  {name:"omar",surname:"caster",age:26},
  {name:"harry",surname:"potter",age:30}
];

// For safer side, First sort the array in ascending order based on age property.
arr.sort((a, b) => a.age - b.age);

// Logic to add the order property in each object of arr.
const res = arr.map((obj, index) => {
  obj.order = index === 0 ? 1 : (arr[index - 1].surname === obj.surname && arr[index - 1].age === obj.age) ? arr[index - 1].order : arr[index - 1].order + 1
  return obj;
});

// Output
console.log(res);
```

Comment: thanks for the help.
this solved my doubt.
I have another, to see if you can help me.
I have the same array but with a new field, let's call it "check", if this field is equal to 1 it has
to follow the normal iteration, even if the first two criterion of surname and age are met..

Comment: original:
[
{order:1,name:"jhon",surname:"connor",age:21},
{order:2,name:"jhonny",surname:"lator",age:22},
{order:3,name:"celia",surname:"mcgregor",age:23},
{order:4,name:"raul",surname:"fernandez",age:25},
{order:4,name:"marcela",surname:"fernandez",age:25},
{order:5,name:"omar",surname:"caster",age:26},
{order:6,name:"moon",surname:"potter",age:30},
{order:6,name:"harry",surname:"potter",age:30},
]

Comment: new:

[
{order:1,name:"jhon",surname:"connor",age:21,check:0},
{order:2,name:"jhonny",surname:"lator",age:22,check:0},
{order:3,name:"celia",surname:"mcgregor",age:23,check:0},
{order:4,name:"raul",surname:"fernandez",age:25,check:0},
{order:4,name:"marcela",surname:"fernandez",age:25,check:0},
{order:5,name:"omar",surname:"caster",age:26,check:0},
{order:6,name:"moon",surname:"potter",age:30,check:1},
{order:7,name:"harry",surname:"potter",age:30, check:0},
]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can add one more condition in the ternary operator `!Obj.check` along with the existing `age` and `surname` condition.

Answer (score 0):

I’d implement it like this

```
const array = [] // your array of objects
const newOrderedArr = array.map((obj, i) => {
if(i === 0) return { …obj, order: 1 };
return { …obj, order: (array[i - 1].surname === obj.surname && array[i - 1].age === obj.age)? array[i - 1].order : array[i - 1].order + 1};
})
```

Assuming that you only check the previous object for similar surnames and ages